# automatic text wrapping messed up with parenthesis

Tags: indentation, wrapping, filetype-markdown

I like to wrap my text to 80 characters all the time, even when I am editing Markdown.

I have a problem when I open parentheses: it doesn't wrap right anymore. Since it is hard for me to explain it, and because a picture is worth a thousand words, here is a screeshot of what is happening:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

If anyone knows how to solve this, this would save my life.

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally `:set lisp` somewhere. It could be other settings such as `'cindent'` as mentioned in @ntnn's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set nocindent` will do the trick. To have that persistent put it in a ftplugin: `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` e.g. (See [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#ftplugin))